# INNER JOIN SQL QUERY

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, join

I'm having a simple problem with this INNER JOIN query...
I have a database, named BCC. I have 2 tables, question and subject.
In the question table, it includes the course and cat(categories) and question.
In the subject table, only ID and subject(same as the category but different field name).

Basically, I fetch all the questions in the question database, but I want them to arranged according to course and cat/subject. I have a accordion style for this feature. The link below, is the screenshot of the display output on this query

```
SELECT `question` FROM question WHERE `course`=$course AND `cat`=$cat;
```

But I look for the INNER JOIN query, and I don't even know which part I get wrong or did I forgot some code to execute the query. I think I scramble them too much that's why I got confused. Here's the SQL Query.

```
SELECT `question` FROM question WHERE `course`=$course AND `cat`=$cat INNER JOIN `subject` ON `subject` WHERE `subject`=`cat`
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: all WHERE clauses should be after INNER JOIN

Comment: Here's the screenshot [link] (http://prntscr.com/6u0m1d) [link]

Comment: That screenshot does not help. Not sure what is that supposed to do.

Comment: Hello Maximus, I have 2 WHERE clause, do you think its appropriate? I'm not sure with my SQL query with INNER JOIN

Comment: You can have any no. of WHERE clauses (separated by AND/OR)

Comment: Wrong. there can be only one WHERE clause, but with any number of conditions separated by AND/OR

Comment: @ZoharPeled that is correct. That is what I meant actually. One WHERE clause with any no. of conditions.

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm still on this problem.. Even order by doesn't work `code` SELECT * FROM `question` INNER JOIN `subject` ON `subject` = `cat` WHERE `course`=$course AND `cat`=$cat ORDER BY `course`; `code`

Comment: Help us to help you: Provide a readable representation of some sample data and desired output

Comment: Hi guys! I'm on a half way I think. I already arranged the questions by subject, but it doesn't go to their respective subjects.. Here's the SQL Query `code` SELECT question.question,question.course,question.cat,question.qid FROM question INNER JOIN subject ON question.cat = subject.subject WHERE `course`=$course AND `cat`=$cat ORDER BY subject.id ASC `code`

Comment: UPDATE! :)

I replace ORDER BY to GROUP BY. I have 4 subjects, Math, Science, English and Logic. But only the Math questions shows in all Subject Section. How do I display all the question by their subject? Here's my updated SQL query now. `code` SELECT question.question,question.course,question.cat,question.qid FROM question INNER JOIN subject ON question.cat = subject.subject WHERE `course`=$course AND `cat`=$cat AND `subject` = `cat` GROUP BY subject.id `code`

thank you!

Comment: Don't use group by if you are not aggregating (e.g. summing, counting, etc.).  Do you have any questions not in the math category?  If there are no science, English, or logic questions, then your inner join will drop those categories from your results.

Comment: Hello @aphrael , thanks for replying. Yes. Like this one on the screenshot [link](http://prntscr.com/6u3ztc)[link] only the first question belongs to Math Section, second is for Science, third is for English and the last is for Logic. Eventually, those four questions displays all the same in all subject section..

Comment: Try `select * from question a left join subject b on a.cat = b.subject order by subject`.  That should return all the questions, and subject info for any of the ones that have a match in the subject table, ordered by table.  If you want it to return each subject as a separate result set, either specify the subject you want (e.g. `where subject = 'Math'`) and duplicate the code for each subject (probably easiest if you just have the four), or write something to loop through the subjects.

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer on my question last night and it is really working :))

```
<?php  
    $subject = $subjectRows['subject']; // subject.subject (MATH, ENGLISH, etc)
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bcc");

       if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
       { 
         echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error(); 
       }

       $questionResult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM question WHERE `cat` = '" . $subject . "' AND `course` = '". $_SESSION['SESS_COURSE'] ."' ");

      while($questionRows = mysqli_fetch_array($questionResult, MYSQL_BOTH)) 
      {  
      echo $questionRows['question'].'?<br>';
      $qid = $questionRows['qid'];
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="qqqq[]" value="'.$qid.'" />';
      echo '<select name="answer[]">';
      echo '<option>Select Answer></option>';
      $resultik = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM choices WHERE question='$qid' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3");
      while($rowik = mysql_fetch_array($resultik))
      {
        echo '<option>';
        echo $rowik['opt'];
        echo '</option>';
      }
      echo '</select><br><br>';
    } 
      mysqli_free_result($questionResult);     
?>
```

Instead of using INNER JOIN in my query, I execute another query and used the variable.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use ON with some matching condition. 
Your query should go like this:

```
SELECT column_list
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON join_condition1

select 
    `question` 
FROM question
INNER JOIN `subject` ON --- keep join condition
WHERE `course`=$course AND `cat`=$cat and `subject`=`cat`
```

Please use **alias** with your tables.

Comment: Hi! This is now my SQL Query `code` SELECT question.question,question.course,question.cat,question.qid FROM question INNER JOIN subject ON question.cat = subject.subject WHERE course=$course AND cat=$cat ORDER BY subject.id ASC `code` But it is still display all the questions in all subject.. I want them to display all the question per subject